# MCPE give command components

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am in the latest version of MCPE beta, 1.1.0.4 and I was wondering what the component thing is on the give command and how to use it.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use CanPlaceOn and CanDestroy in Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/374598/how-can-i-use-canplaceon-and-candestroy-in-bedrock-edition). This is, admittedly, a close call, but I still think these are fundamentally the same question from two different angles

Answer (score 5):

As far as I have found, these work (at least in the 1.1.0.8 beta). Both will use the same block, etc. in the examples, yet it does work a bit on non-placables, and not being able to use liquids or air as a target.

```
/give @p stone 1 0 {"can_destroy":{"blocks":["dirt","glass"]}}
/give @p stone 1 0 {"can_place_on":{"blocks":["dirt","glass"]}}
```

Answer (score 1):

`/give player` (you or anyone else) `block` (doesn't have to be a specific block, it can be a weapon, etc. Underscore replaces space) `amount` (number)

This is a real example of it:

```
/give Steve diamond_sword
```

(amount is not needed for a single thing)

Answer (score 0):

Example:

`/give @p diamond_pickaxe 1 0 {“**minecraft:can_destroy**:{“blocks”:[“stone”,”diamond_block”]}}`

The two components are

`{“minecraft:can_destroy”`
And
`{“minecraft:can_place_on”`

Answer (score -1):

/give @s concrete 1 0 {"minecraft:can_place_on":{"blocks":["dirt"]}}
This is a valid command for the tag:"Can Be Placed On:"block" This is valid for MC Bedrock Edition and MCPE.

Answer (score -3):

```
{
    "format_version": "1.10.0",
    "minecraft:block": {
        "description": {
            "identifier": "more:netherstar_ore",
            "is_experimental": false,
            "register_to_creative_menu": true
        },
        "components": {
            "minecraft:loot": {
                "table": "loot_tables/blocks/netherstar_ore.json"
            },
            "minecraft:destroy_time": {
                "value": 7
            },
            "minecraft:explosion_resistance": {
                "value": 1
            },
            "minecraft:flammable": {
                "flame_odds": 0,
                "burn_odds": 0
            },
            "minecraft:block_light_absorption": {
                "value": 1
            },
            "minecraft:block_light_emission": {
                "emission": 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What block is this talking about? Or is it just an example?