# NBT Syntax in MCPE

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

MCPE 1.1.0 added NBT, such as `CanDestroy` and `CanPlaceOn`, which can be accessed from `/replaceitem` and `/give`. However, the PC syntax doesn't seem to work.

```
/give @p iron_shovel 1 0 {CanDestroy:["dirt"]}
```

gives me `Invalid syntax`.

Anyone know what the new syntax is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MCPE uses JSON syntax instead of NBT:

```
/give @p iron_shovel 1 0 {"can_destroy":{"blocks":["dirt"]}}
/give @p dirt 1 0 {"can_place_on":{"blocks":["grass"]}}
```

[Original post (From beta)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/307584/188341)