# How do I get a map with specific X and Z centers in the Bedrock Engine?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I tried creating maps, then zooming them out, they are not centered at `(0 0)`.

I tried using the `/give` command with `{scale:1,dimension:0,xCenter:0,zCenter:0}` at the end, guess what I got? SYNTAX ERROR!!

Can anybody help me create a map with a scale of 1, centered at `(0 0)`??

P.S. I am playing from my XBox...

Comment: In the bedrock engine, you have to use double quotes around each tag name like this: `{"scale":1,"dimension":0}` according to [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/310411/nbt-syntax-in-mcpe/310656) webpage. I don't have bedrock edition, so I don't want to post it as an answer just yet.

Comment: I'm pretty sure NBT doesn't work in PE, only CanPlaceOn and CanDestroy.

Comment: @D-Inventor ill try that.

Comment: the full command should be /give @p minecraft:filled_map 1 0 {scale:1,dimension:0,xCenter:0,zCenter:0}